# Mockito how SmartNullPointerException helps me?

Tags: mockito

Just got to know about the possibility in `Mockito`, to us `SmartNullPointerException` (which basically sets `RETURNS_SMART_NULLS`.

But I do not quite understand how it helps me. It's just a wrap over the regular NPE. What am I missing?

Comment: Does the documentation for [`RETURNS_SMART_NULLS`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_SMART_NULLS) answer your question? "smartNull gives nicer exception message than NPE because it points out the line where unstubbed method was called. You just click on the stack trace."

Comment: Yes, thanks. Missed it.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation for [RETURNS_SMART_NULLS](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_SMART_NULLS):

`This implementation can be helpful when working with legacy code. Unstubbed methods often return null. If your code uses the object returned by an unstubbed call you get a NullPointerException. This implementation of Answer returns SmartNull instead of null. SmartNull gives nicer exception message than NPE because it points out the line where unstubbed method was called. You just click on the stack trace.`